# Running route and KM counting - android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, gps, distance

I'm trying to create a running application and I need to get information about the distance and the map-route. I want to show the distance live when using this app. How can I get this information? (i also want it to run on background) I trying to use map view but I couldn't find how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using google waypoint(direction) api this api will give you points between two locations using this points you can draw path as well and also its giving distance between that points and also this will giving you all info in background.